# I am getting the error that the local variable cruty referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django

Getting the error local variable 'cruty' referenced before assignment

```
def index(request):
    if request.method =="POST":
        fname= request.POST.get("fname",None)
        if fname is not None:
            dname= Students.objects.get(USN=fname)
            print(dname)
            cruty= Marks.objects.filter(students=dname)
            print(cruty)
    return render(request, "index.html", {"cruty": cruty})
```

Comment: Indent code properly by editing question using `{}` button. I t will help what you actually doing wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `cruty` if `request.method` is not `POST`?

Comment: define `cruty = None` before `if request.method =="POST":`

Answer (score 0):

```
def index(request):
    if request.method =="POST":
        cruty = None
        fname = request.POST.get("fname",None)
        if fname is not None:
            dname= Students.objects.get(USN=fname)
            print(dname)
            cruty= Marks.objects.filter(students=dname)
            print(cruty)
        return render(request, "index.html", {"cruty": cruty})
```

Always make sure that the variable you are accessing is in the scope of the block of code, e.g. you are trying to access cruty outside the

```
if fname is not None
```

condition, but cruty is not visible in return, so you can define the variable in that scope, and that would work

Comment: Thank you so much for the insight.

Comment: Great! Glad to help! @Amitpoddar :) Please consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking the tick next to the answer :) Also consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers as well